# Android: Ensuring that TextView cannot display a String value the same as its colour?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing a game based on the [STROOP EFFECT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stroop_effect).

This game is based on the displaying of a string of a certain colour for the user to see.

However this String value cannot be the same as its Colour.

I.e. this is ok (as "RED" is not actually the colour Red, it is blue):

[image]

But this is not ok as "RED" actually is the color Red:

[image]

How can I ensure that the 2nd option **cannot** occur within my game?

**Specific related code section:**

```
color = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvStroopColor);
    int randString = new Random().nextInt(stringOnScreen.length);
            int randColor = new Random().nextInt(colorsOnScreen.length);

            // set the text of the string in textview for user to see
            color.setText("" + stringOnScreen[randString]);
            color.setTextColor((int) colorsOnScreen[randColor]);
```

**Full Activity:**

```
public class Stroop extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

        HashMap<String, Integer> colors = new HashMap<>();
        // putting the strings and color vals of the hashmap to an array
        Object stringOnScreen[];
        Object colorsOnScreen[];

        // declare vars
        TextView color;
        Button btn1;
        Button btn2;
        TextView result;
        TextView showScore;
        TextView seeMed;
        TextView seeAtt;

        int score=0;
        MediaPlayer tenSecs;
        // vars related to neurosky

        BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
        TGDevice device;
        TGEegPower eegPower;
        final boolean rawEnabled = true;

        List<Integer> meditationValues = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int averageMedLevel;
        int totalofMedLevels;
        int medCount = 0;
        int medMax;

        // for attention
        List<Integer> AttentionValues = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int averageAttLevel;
        int totalofAttLevels;
        int attCount = 0;
        int attMax;

        // used for displaying seconds left
        EditText countdown;

        // in relation to saving values to file
        List<TGEegPower> medPoints = new ArrayList<TGEegPower>();
        File dir;
        int medValueToWrite;
        int attValueToWrite;

        // in relation to the results display in next activity
        ArrayList<Score> singleScore;
        Score single;

        private Random random = new Random();




        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.stroop);

            setUpGame();

            stringOnScreen = colors.keySet().toArray();
            colorsOnScreen = colors.values().toArray();

            setUpQuestion();

            btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
            btn1.setOnClickListener(this);




        }// oncreate end

        public void setUpQuestion() {

            int[] buttons = new int[]{R.id.btnStroop1, R.id.btnStroop2};
            int first = random.nextInt(2);

            btn1 = (Button) findViewById(buttons[first]); //btnstroop1 or btnstroop2
            btn2 = (Button) findViewById(buttons[1-first]); //the opposite btn

            int randString = new Random().nextInt(stringOnScreen.length);
            int randColor = new Random().nextInt(colorsOnScreen.length);

            // set the text of the string in textview for user to see
            color.setText("" + stringOnScreen[randString]);
            color.setTextColor((int) colorsOnScreen[randColor]);


            btn1.setText("" + stringOnScreen[randString]); //Set btn1 to the string val

            setBtn2Text();

            showScore.setText("Score= " + score);

        }

        public void setUpGame() {

            // setting up the hashmap
            colors.put("Green", Color.GREEN);
            colors.put("Blue", Color.BLUE);
            colors.put("Red", Color.RED);
            colors.put("Yellow", Color.YELLOW);
            colors.put("Black", Color.BLACK);

            // setting up vars
            color = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvStroopColor);
            result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvStroopResults);
            showScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvStroopScore);
            seeMed = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvStroopSeeMeditation);
            seeAtt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvStroopSeeAttention);
            tenSecs= MediaPlayer.create(Stroop.this, R.raw.tenseconds);
            countdown= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etStroopCountdown);

        }

        public void setBtn2Text(){
            switch(color.getCurrentTextColor()){
                case Color.GREEN:
                    btn2.setText("Green");
                    break;
                case Color.RED:
                    btn2.setText("Red");
                    break;
                case Color.BLUE:
                    btn2.setText("Blue");
                    break;
                case Color.YELLOW:
                    btn2.setText("Yellow");
                    break;
                case Color.BLACK:
                    btn2.setText("Black");
                    break;

            }
        }

        public void onClick(View v) {

             if(checkForMatchBtn2((Button) v)){

                    result.setText("Correct!");
                    result.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                    score++;
             }else{
                    result.setText("Wrong!");
                    result.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                }

            setUpQuestion();
        }

        public boolean checkForMatchBtn2(Button btn2){
            if(color.getCurrentTextColor() == Color.GREEN && btn2.getText().equals("Green"))
                return true;
            else if(color.getCurrentTextColor() == Color.RED && btn2.getText().equals("Red"))
                return true;
            else if(color.getCurrentTextColor() == Color.BLACK && btn2.getText().equals("Black"))
                return true;
            else if(color.getCurrentTextColor() == Color.YELLOW && btn2.getText().equals("Yellow"))
                return true;
            else if(color.getCurrentTextColor() == Color.BLUE && btn2.getText().equals("Blue"))
                return true;
            else 
                return false;
        }

        public boolean checkForMatchBtn1(Button btn1){
            if(color.getCurrentTextColor() == Color.GREEN && btn1.getText().equals("Green"))
                return true;
            else if(color.getCurrentTextColor() == Color.RED && btn1.getText().equals("Red"))
                return true;
            else if(color.getCurrentTextColor() == Color.BLACK && btn1.getText().equals("Black"))
                return true;
            else if(color.getCurrentTextColor() == Color.YELLOW && btn1.getText().equals("Yellow"))
                return true;
            else if(color.getCurrentTextColor() == Color.BLUE && btn1.getText().equals("Blue"))
                return true;
            else 
                return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please don't prefix your question titles with tag names like Android, Java etc, the tags at the bottom are enough to show the target of the question. As your two array are matched, randomly extracting the same `randString` and `randColor` means you have a string color in that color. `while (true) { // the two lines to randomly extract randString and randColor; if (randString != randColor) {break;}}`.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a Map, fulfill it with every options you don't want where String is your color and int its hex value.

Then you only need to check if the color chosen exists with the hex chosen in your Map. 
So if you get White and #FFF, you'll check what's the associated color of "white" in your map and if it's #FFF, that random is forbidden.

There may be a better way but that will do the trick =)

Answer (score 0):

You could set a condition before displaying the text and reload a new color/text if they are the "same", something like:

```
color = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvStroopColor);
int randString = new Random().nextInt(stringOnScreen.length);
int randColor = new Random().nextInt(colorsOnScreen.length);
if(!colors.get(stringOnScreen[randString]).equals(colorsOnScreen[randColor])){
        // set the text of the string in textview for user to see
        color.setText("" + stringOnScreen[randString]);
        color.setTextColor((int) colorsOnScreen[randColor]);
}else{
 // recall your function !
}
```

You should also avoid the findViewById inside your function (it could slow the application) but only retrieve the correct button and then set the text

Answer (score 0):

You could do for example something like this

```
  public void setUpQuestion() {
       ..
       int randString = new Random().nextInt(stringOnScreen.length);
       int randColor = new Random().nextInt(colorsOnScreen.length);

       //regenerate question if color and string are the same
       setUpQuestion()  
       ...
```

Or you could do make a clone of the colection reduce it and then select a random color from the reduced collection

```
    ..
    HashMap<String, Integer> colorsReduced  = (HashMap<String, Integer>)colors.clone();
    colorsReduced.remove(randString);
    colorsReduced.get( new Random().nextInt(colorsReduced.size()-1));
    ...
```